# Are any of the X-Men comic covers or pages in the movie Logan pre-existing?

Tags: marvel, x-men, logan

In the movie *Logan* (2017) there are a number of *X-Men* comic covers and pages.

[image: Deadpool's BFF reads a funny book]

I looked up the cover to one issue (#132? The funeral cover) featured on-screen, and it did not match the cover I found online. I know there are sometimes "news-stand" covers and "direct-market" covers (not to mention variants). I was wondering if some or all of the comic book art was made for the movie, or if some was pre-existing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All of the comic covers were made specifically for the movie.

According to [this interview with director James Mangold at Slashfilm](http://www.slashfilm.com/interview-logan-director-james-mangold/),

> **Logan also incorporates the idea of X-Men comics in a really interesting way. So first of all, how many of those comics are actual comics that exist, and then how many did you make up? And second, how did the idea come to you?**
>
> We had to make them all. Marvel only agreed to let me do this as long as we didn’t use any real Marvel comics. So we made them all up. But they involved existing Marvel characters. But they just couldn’t be real Marvel comics. You’d have to go ask Marvel why.

Another [article on The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2017/3/6/14821492/logan-x-men-comic-books-wolverine) reveals the covers were created by artist Dan Panosian with some interior art by Joe Quesada, and has quotes from Panosian on the assignment:

> In all, Panosian created 10 fake covers for the comics used in the film, while “Joe Quesada penciled four pages that I inked / colored and lettered that you see featured throughout the film.”
>
> He received open-ended directions on what the covers should look like. “The themes were easy to select,” he noted, because the films covered many of the same elements as the stories that he had grown up reading.

Comment: That's interesting. One wonders why Marvel would not allow their flagship film to use some comic covers.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Marvel likely doesn't consider Logan their flagship film, because Fox controls those rights, not Marvel alone.  As I understand it, there's been other occasional incidents where Marvel's cooperation has been only partial or begrudging. Some people believe X-Men have been sidelined in comics storylines because they consider it "advertising for another company" to make really cool stories that Fox could later adapt.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the whole Fox vs. Marvel thing. Well, no harm done.

Comment: @Gallifreyan No harm done. Except for the fallout of the whole Fox vs. Marvel thing.

Comment: I like, upvoted, and accepted your answer. Might I request you credit who the interview was with, beyond a link with slashfilm? It's nice to know who is being quoted without having to click through. I assumed James Mangold, but it's nice to know. Also, is this an intentional gap for comic/movie canons? This might be intentional... (rising organ music)

Comment: @Gallifreyan I'd think it has something to do with how you treat continuity and stuff. If they'd show actual covers, people could imply that all real world Marvel comic releases exist in this movie's universe, which would basically imply quite some storyline issues. How would Stan Lee be able to come up with those superheroes years before many of them are actually born? Is he a mutant as well? So I think they basically wanted them to create their own continuity of comics that are actually based on real heroes heard of or as seen e.g. on TV. No "characters are fictional, any resemblance…"

Comment: Logan even comments that most of it (the comics) was made up, and the bits that weren't were different. It's a nice CYA moment.

Comment: And now Disney, who owns Marvel, is trying to buy Fox and if that happens, all of this will be unnecessary.